# virtualenv: cannot import name 'main'

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm having a little trouble with virtualenv on Mac OS X Yosemite. After I couldn't run virtualenv at all first, I installed Python 3 via `brew` (previously I installed it via the package on python.org). I linked this installation of python3, updated pip and ran `pip3 install virtualenv`. When I try to run virtualenv (e.g. `$ virtualenv --python=python3 ../virtualenv`), I get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv import main
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv.py", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your virtualenv executable `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` is importing the virtualenv package `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv.py`. My guess is that package is not the one the executable should really be importing. The reason it is choosing that one is because it is in the same directory.

First, check where the real virtualenv package is. In the python3 terminal:

```
>>> import virtualenv
>>> virtualenv.__file__
```

If it is not `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv.py`, then the simplest way to get `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` to import it instead of `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv.py` is to delete `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv.py` (or so you can easily undo this if it doesn't work, simply rename `virtualenv.py` to something else like `xvirtualenvx.py`).

Comment: That other file is probably left over from some other attempt at installing virtualenv or from another version of python. If you open it up, you'll probably see that it's the same file as the file that you're executing. It might be tied to a different version of python, which you would see in the shebang at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 18):

After my upgrade to Fedora 32 I had the same issue which lead me to this question:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'virtualenv'
```

In my case I actually seemed to have both `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` as well as `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py`.

Removing the user virtualenv version and reinstalling it into the system with root fixed the issue:

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
```

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: This is not the right way to go about it. User may not want to install virtualenv in the system folders and contain everything in home folder

Answer (score 8):

I received this error after upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to **20.04 LTS**. So there were two problems all at once. First the python version was still running 2.x and doing a simple update or try to uninstall (`apt-get remove virtualenv`) of virtualenv did not help at all. But I found a solution. First let 20.04 LTS 'know' the times of using old python is over:

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3
```

Then test it and open a console to get the version string with `python -V`; by now it should be showing something like *Python 3.8.5*. Fine.

Next step is to solve the `virtualenv` problem. I tried to find out, which executable was run with `which virtualenv` and it showed: `$HOME/.local/bin/virtualenv`. Hmmkay, somehow the system wasn't using the `/usr/bin/virtualenv` executable. I thought maybe I let the directory become invisible (a.k.a. renaming) and maybe the system will go on a hunt for an alternative `virtualenv` running:

```
mv $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenv /home/$USER/.local/bin/virtualenv_OLD
```

Then I simply changed into a playground-directory and ran `virtualenv donaldknuth` and behold - it worked. To be sure I ran another `which virtualenv` and the system returned a `/usr/bin/virtualenv`. Last check to do was activating the new virtual environment:

```
source $HOME/playground/donaldknuth/bin/activate
```

The terminal changed and it worked fine. Solution

**EDIT:**

Based on Pierre B.'s suggestion you may have to restart your Shell. The command `hash -d virtualenv` will delete the stored location of `virtualenv` from the shell's cache and determine the correct path right now. (Sources: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/hash.htm, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)

Comment: Solved it for me. Not that using bash you may need to restart your bash session or run `hash -r` as cache would point to old `virtualenv` path (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables)

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: Why that weird (and wrong) command? You probably want `$USER` instead of `USER`, but it's more consistent to pass the root path the same in both instances (source and target): `mv $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenv $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenv_OLD`

Comment: worked for me. in my case I had to install specific python /pip versions. After removing from /usr/local/bin , it picked up virtualenv from /usr/bin which linked to the right dist-packages folder

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to some others here, I had multiple installations of virtualenv. Not sure where the extra one came from, but I had these two:

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
/usr/bin/virtualenv
```

One is from apt install of virtualenv, the other from pip install of virtualenv.

This happened when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux Mint 20, I had to [switch default Python interpreter to `python3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61210682/802365)

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1
```

Then remove existing `virtualenv` and reinstall via `pip` and `python3`:

```
rm ~/.local/bin/virtualenv 
apt remove python3-virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenv
```