# django installation error under virtual environment

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install Django via pip installer under virtual environment.

I followed following steps:-

1. Installing virtual environment
2. Activating virtual environment
3. Installing Django using pip, this is where I am facing problem.

The command I typed in command prompt is as follows:

```
C:\hello-world\venv\Scripts\pip install Django==1.7.1
```

The error I am getting is:-

```
 c:\hello-world\venv\Scripts>pip install Django==1.7.1
ack (most recent call last):
 "c:\miniconda3\Lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
_main__", mod_spec)
 "c:\miniconda3\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
ec(code, run_globals)
 "c:\hello-world\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
Error: cannot import name 'main'
```

Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: I guess either your virtual environment is not properly activated or installed correctly. Try running python shell perform basic python operations, if they are working or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtualenv: cannot import name 'main'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853481/virtualenv-cannot-import-name-main)

Comment: what happens if you use "conda" as per [the documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html)

Comment: I removed miniconda and installed Python 2.7 , now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I removed miniconda and installed Python 2.7 , now it's working fine