# How to change python3 to default in linux mint

Tags: python-3.x, linux-mint

I have a little problem with changing python3 to default in newly installed operating system linux Mint 19.3. It was pretty easy on Ubuntu 16.04 but now I need small help here.

So, I run

```
python --version
```

and got this

```
Python 2.7.15+
```

Than I run

```
python3 --version
```

and this was the result

```
Python 3.6.8
```

After entering this command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

I received obvious info

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python
```

Both version of python are located in /usr/bin folder. 
The issue occurs when I'm trying to change python3 to as a default by typing the command

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6
```

The terminal outputs the following

```
update-alternatives: --install needs <link> <name> <path> <priority>
```

Any help here would be welcome.

Comment: Checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt)
Also, I've been into the same problem before, I highly recommend that you either use an alias or use [python virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/) Once I was so frustrated with python 2.x that I just removed it! the next thing I knew was that my gnome failed to start and hand to reinstall a whole lot of packages.

Answer (score 15):

In your case, priority is missing, just append `1` at the end of the command like this :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 1
```

Comment: Update: this requires a 'priority' value at the end. I ended up running this: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10` to alias the 'python3' alias as `python`

Answer (score 1):

@darkfidis answer is correct. But you may also need to run to set or change the default python version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Answer (score 0):

To define python3 as your default version of python on linux, you need to add a specific line to `.bashrc` file located in your home directory.
Here is a simple method to do so through command line interface (termianl).

Run:

```sh
$ echo "alias python='python3'" >> .bashrc
$ source .bashrc
```

then run `python --version` to check if the change has applied.

Comment: Works ok with ZSH too, replace `.bashrc` with `.zshrc` however this defeats the purpose of using `update-alternatives` and would require resourcing or restart shell if you decided to switch default python version in an active session.