# "exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: python

I am running **Arduion IDE 1.8.12** on **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**.

I am trying to compile Example code for ESP32 Camera module (standard camera module with default example on Arduino IDE) and I got this error (which I think is not Arduino issue, but Python):

```
"exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH
Error compiling for board ESP32 Wrover Module"
```

Same message with all ESP32.

I also did sudo apt install python. Got back this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python is already the newest version (2.7.15~rc1-1).
0 modernizētas, 0 instalētas no jauna, 0 tiks noņemtas un 6 netiks modernizētas.
```

When I type Python in Terminal, got this back:

```
Python 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09)
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Thank you for help!

BR,
Valters

Comment: Do you mean to be using python 2.7? Usually 3.x is recommended as 2.7 is deprecated and no longer being supported.

Comment: What is the command that you run? esptool.py?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim the version of python installed on Ubuntu and other Debian based distros is 2.7, so it is not unusual to see 2.7 used.
Also, I have updated the version of python to 3.6.9 and I am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve & Fixed the following upload error from Arduino To ESP32-CAM (And for ESP32 too):
environment: ubuntu 20.04 64bit, Arduino 1.8.13 ESP32-CAM And yp-05 (for ESP's serial connection)

- exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH
- Error compiling for board AI Thinker ESP32-CAM.

The solution is:

1. Installing the package (for example python-is-python3_3.8.2-4_all):

`sudo dpkg -i python-is-python3_3.8.2-4_all.deb`
2) Wiring

WIRES colors:      | black  | NO    | WHITE  | GRAY       |  BROWN       |  EMPTY
yp-05 legs ordere: |  GRD   | EMPTY |  VCC   | TX         |  RX          |   DIR
esp32s CAM:        |  GRD   | EMPTY |  3.3V  | GPIO 3 UOR |  GPIO 1 UOT  |  EMPTY

*** just For Upload: SHORT ESP32-CAM 100 & GRD

I hope it will save time to start using ESP32-CAM (And ESP32 too).

That's it - Solved & Run!

Answer (score 13):

I created a symbolic link as such, linking python with python3, it worked for my ubuntu 18.04 machine

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Work in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS !!

Comment: "operation not permitted" while running this command on MacOS Sonoma (M1).

Answer (score 12):

In MacOS
running this command in Terminal.app under your current user

```
sed -i -e 's/=python /=python3 /g' ~/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/*/platform.txt
```

seems to fix it.The command modifies all the platform.txt files under your local installation of the ESP32 tools (~/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32) and replaces the word python by python3 wherever it finds it

Comment: Solved for me! Thanks! :)

Comment: I update Monterey 12.5.1, i had the error. This solved it.

Answer (score 10):

I did this for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
apt install python-is-python3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on MacOs 12 and above please edit the platform file, change from python to python3 as follows; preferences->user/path/arduino/packages/hardware/esp32/version/platform.txt and edit the line that looks as follows:tools.gen_esp32part.cmd=python3 "{runtime.platform.path}/tools/gen_esp32part.py"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than make a symlink, on Ubuntu and derivatives, you can make "python" the default with the alternatives facility.  See this question and answer, but just reference python3 rather than python3.6.

[How to change python3 to default in linux mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916531/how-to-change-python3-to-default-in-linux-mint)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today (building for the TTGO T-Watch 2020); it was because I was using the Flatpak version of Arduino and it didn't include a straight `python` binary (only `python3`).

Confirmed with:

```
$ flatpak run --command=ls cc.arduino.arduinoide -l /usr/bin/|grep python
lrwxrwxrwx  1 nfsnobody nfsnobody       9 Feb  5 16:30 python3 -> python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  2 nfsnobody nfsnobody   14512 Jan  1  1970 python3.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 nfsnobody nfsnobody      17 Feb  5 16:30 python3.7-config -> python3.7m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 nfsnobody nfsnobody       9 Feb  5 16:30 python3.7m -> python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  2 nfsnobody nfsnobody    3309 Jan  1  1970 python3.7m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 nfsnobody nfsnobody      16 Feb  5 16:30 python3-config -> python3.7-config
```

I'm not sure of the "right" solution, but after some trial and error the winning workaround seemed to be:

```
$ cd /var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08/active/files/bin
$ sudo ln -s python3 python
```

Of course, then I ran into another problem (no pyserial)...