# Error occurs when deploying using buildozer

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtualenv, buildozer

I was deploying android app that I made.
when running
buildozer android debug deploy run
import error occurs.
any suggestions?

RAN: /home/sen/.local/bin/virtualenv --python=python3 venv

STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sen/.local/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in 
    from virtualenv import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [virtualenv: cannot import name 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853481/virtualenv-cannot-import-name-main)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+from+virtualenv+import+main

Comment: I tried renaming. It recreates the file and makes the same error.

Comment: I got around the error by upgrading pip3